# Tasks in airflow not running in order

Tags: airflow

- I'm using airflow to automatize some machine learning models. Everything it's successfull but i have issues according to the order of the tasks.
- I have a 7 tasks running in paralel and the last two tasks must start when those 7 tasks finish.

At the time 6 tasks finishes, the last two start without waiting for the 7th taks to finish.

---

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0TNu.png) the image of whats happening.

Comment: Check the [`trigger_rule`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules) of your `creation_order_cell_task`. To get the behaviour you want, it should be either `ALL_SUCCESS` (default) or `ALL_DONE`

Comment: Thanks! For some reason the default was not that. You saved me from making another dag haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It appears that [`trigger_rule`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules) of your `creation_order_cell_task` is incorrect (fot the desired behaviour)
- To get the behaviour you want, it should be either `ALL_SUCCESS` (default) or `ALL_DONE`